# Bitshifts to obtain remainder

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, number-theory

I want to know how to obtain the remainder by dividing an integer with another integer (both positive) using bitshift or bitwise operators only. The `/` operator or `%` operator should not be used.

For example, for obtaining the remainder when divisor is of the form `2^k` the following operation yields the remainder.

`m = Remainder`

`n = The number`

`d = The divisor`

`m = n & ( d - 1 )`

However this method works only when `d` is of the form `2^k` . I want to know a similar method for non-powers of `2`. I am currently working on a problem from `programming challenges` and want to employ such a method to reduce program execution time

Comment: Wouldn't the fact that the bit representation is only in base-2 be a limitation?  Consider the value 43/7 - the value is actually 6.142857... .  What generic approach have you considered for a value in a base higher than 2?

Comment: There is no general method. You can replace the division with a multiplication and some shifts and additions/subtractions if you know the divisor, though. Ask any competent C compiler about it, and it will give you the magic values for any compile time constant.

Comment: Unless the answer involves only 1 bitshift statement, I'd bet you don't beat javas mod operator.

Comment: @rambocoder If you hardcode the magic multiplier and shift distances, it should beat a division on most CPUs. But that is of course limited to divisors you know at compile time.

Comment: I found [this link](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ModulusDivision). It alone doesn't qualify for an answer, but it's probably enough to get you on your way.

Comment: @Makoto The above approach works for a value in a base higher than 2. However all the numbers have to be converted to binary beforehand. Most compilers inherently work with binary numbers.So this should not be a problem

Comment: Modulus is already very fast (the IDIV opcode in x86 or amd64 already calculates modulus; it takes ~30 ticks to do so). I really doubt that slow divisions are the problem - there is probably an algorithm that requires less operations (not necessarily faster) as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any answer that doesn't use the operator `%` will be a less efficient answer, but, if you absolutely cannot use the operator, then, one solution is to use a loop to subtract d from n repeatedly:

```
m = n;
while (m >= d)
{
  m -= d;
}
```

Assuming that your integers are 32-bit, then you can consider an optimized version where we delete multiples of d from n:

```
m = n;
for (i = 31; i >= 0; i--)
{
  di = d << i;
  if (di > 0 && m >= di) m -= di;
}
```

This example, assumes the integers are signed and watches for overflow i.e. the test for `di > 0`.

Comment: unfortunately, an overflowing shift doesn't necessarily result in a negative number, even if you assume a normal 2s-complement machine.